# Message parameter doesn't allow html, so tried to use message_tags parameter in this format

Tags: ios, facebook

Message parameter doesn't allow html, so tried to use message_tags parameter in this format, but with real values(format from here http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/592/):

```
{
"19": [
{
"id": 101961456910,
"name": "Marmot",
"offset": 19,
"length": 6
}
],
"0": [
{
"id": 1207059,
"name": "Dhiren Patel",
"offset": 0,
"length": 12
}
]
}
```

and no result. Tried different values, there are no errors, but no result.

Answer (score 0):

The message_tags parameter isn't one you can set via the API.

Did you find documentation suggesting otherwise? invalid parameters are for the most part silently ignored when you make a POST request